# How to use In-app updates in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have follwed the official documention to implement in-App- update in jetpack compose.

used below code inside compose fun, but here the code inside addOnSuccessListener is never called.

```
val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(LocalContext.current)
    val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
       if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
        // This example applies an immediate update. To apply a flexible update
        // instead, pass in AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
        && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
    ) {
        // Request the update.
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck in this a few days ago. Make sure to check these:

1. Downgrade the versionCode of the app to something lower than the latest version on Playstore.
2. Use the **signed release APK** to test AppUpdateManager.
3. Use the same signature used for making a release on PlayStore.